# if anything in collections do such segment reversing ? | python

Tags: python, collections, dictionary

`(a,b), (c,d), (e,f), (g,h) => (b, c), (d, e), (f, g)`

so we omit first and last and process reverse segments

I hit this third time and always I write own code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing either in `collections` or `itertools`.

One could [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) the pairs, drop the first and last element with [`islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), and then use the [`grouper`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe to turn them into pairs, but you still need to define the `grouper` function yourself.

I would just define my own optimized utility function for this.

```
def shift(pairs):
    it = iter(pairs)
    (_, p) = next(it)
    for (n, p2) in it:
        yield (p, n)
        p = p2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
>>> tups=[('a','b'), ('c','d'), ('e','f'), ('g','h')]
>>> zip(*[iter([e for t in tups for e in t][1:-1])]*2)
[('b', 'c'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g')]
```

### *Edit*

The code I posted is most assuredly NOT 'an order of magnitude slower' than using itertools or KennyTM's solution:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

li=[('a','b'), ('c','d'), ('e','f'), ('g','h')]

def t1(tups):
    return zip(*[iter([e for t in tups for e in t][1:-1])]*2)

def t2(tups):
    def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
        "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
        # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)        
    flat=itertools.chain.from_iterable(tups)
    sl=itertools.islice(flat,1,len(tups)*2-1)        
    return list(grouper(sl,2))

def t3(pairs):
    it = iter(pairs)
    (_, p) = next(it)
    for (n, p2) in it:
        yield (p, n)
        p = p2                    

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    import timeit 
    n=1000000
    print(t1(li),t2(li), list(t3(li)))
    assert t1(li)==t2(li)==list(t3(li))
    print(timeit.timeit("t1(li)", setup="from __main__ import t1, li",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("t2(li)", setup="from __main__ import t2, li, itertools",number=n))
    print(timeit.timeit("list(t3(li))", setup="from __main__ import t3, li",number=n))
```

Prints:

```
3.02761888504
4.29241204262
2.12067294121
```

Which shows they are all roughly the same speed. KennyTM's is fastes, but not by an order of magnitude.

Comment: I only have access to PyPy at the moment, but this is an order of magnitude slower than [KennyTM's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576598/2093785) answer.